# Let $V$ be a vector space. What is quotient space $V/\{0\}$?

Tags: vector-spaces

How I understand this right now:

$V/\{0\} = \{v + \{0\} | \forall v \in V \}$.

So each coset is, fora any $v \in V$, $v +\{0\} = \{v+0\} = \{v\}$.

So, $V/\{0\}=\{\{v\}|\forall v \in V\}$, which is $\textbf{not}$ the same as $V$ since every element of $V/\{0\}$ is a set containing a single element of $V$. But my textbook says $V/\{0\}=V$.

I have seen the complement problem, [Why isn't the quotient space $V/V = \{ V \}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970868/why-isnt-the-quotient-space-v-v-v)

but I'm still not understanding something...

Please help me understand what I'm confused about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map $v\rightarrow\{v\}$ is isomorphic as vector spaces: $\{v\}+\{w\}=\{v+w\}$, $k\{v\}=\{kv\}$, and if $\{v\}=\{0\}$, then $v=0$.

So we identify $V$ and $V/\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for making it so explicit!

Answer (score 2):

Well! Your book uses abuse of language, it's obviously unequal but since it is Isomorphic then we can say they are same structurally.
Hope it works

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!